# How can one make an animation run only once per session only at the beginning of the session using jQuery?

Tags: cookies, jquery, loading, jquery-animate

### Goal

During the loading of the site have a div fixed to the top of the browser window named `#topbar` start off at `height: 100%` & `opacity: 1.0` and `.animate()` down to `height: 2px` & `opacity: 0.2`.

This animation will broadcast upon the loading of any page of the site; it just has to be the first page load of each new session. If a visitor leaves the site and then reloads any page from it 5 minutes later, they will see this same animation take place once again.

**How can one accomplish this via jQuery?**

Comment: via jQuery alone? storing the state in a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

With that in mind I would use Ajax to set some sort of Session.
ie: `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['animate']=true; $_SESSION['animate_time']=time(); ?>`

And you can check if the session is set and the time when it was created.

```
<?php
$time_till_animate = 60*5;//5 minutes
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['animate']) && isset($_SESSION['animate_time'])){
if((time()-$_SESSION['animate_time']) > $time_till_animate){
     //Animate
}}else{
     //Animate
}
```

from then on you are set.

PS: I'm sure there are plenty of better ways to do it. (not sure if you use PHP, just ignore if you dont)

Answer (score 2):

cookies the best way as The Scrum Meister pointed.

check is there any foobar cookie
if yes than not to do the animaztion,
if not then set a cookie for 5 minutes expire or what
start the animation

and another code is good: on every page create an ajax function which resets the expiration time

for example

```
setcookie(date) //this sets your cookies you should implement for yourself
func setagain() {
    setcookie(expanded_date);
    window.setTimeot(setagain,10000);
} 

if(iscookie() == true) {
setagain()
}
else {
animate()
setagain();
}
```

cookies tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp